# Scrollytelling/parallax html story

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to coding, but i want to make a scrollytelling page with similar effects as the start of this page: https://www.vg.no/annonsorinnhold/frelsesarmeen/fattigdom-i-norge/

I want the text on top of the image to be scrolled with the user, and the background to change seamlessly when the text reaches the top of the page. So it has the illusion that the user is not scrolling from section to section.

This is what i have tried, but i do not quite understand how to make it flow the way i want

I am not very skilled with js, so as little as possible would be nice.

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
  sections.forEach(section => {
    const textbox = section.querySelector('.textbox');
    const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
    if (scrollPosition >= sectionTop) {
      textbox.classList.add('fixed');
    } else {
      textbox.classList.remove('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.one {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300/FF5733/FFFFFF");
}

.two {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300/3498db/FFFFFF");
}

.three {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300/2ecc71/FFFFFF");
}

.textbox {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="section one">
    <div class="textbox">
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
      <p>This is the first section. Add your text here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section two">
    <div class="textbox">
      <h2>Section 2</h2>
      <p>This is the second section. Add your text here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section three">
    <div class="textbox">
      <h2>Section 3</h2>
      <p>This is the third section. Add your text here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```